# Laravel $request->all() is returning nothing in response to an ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

My ajax request shown below sends a json object to a backend function which is supposed to return `$request->all()` but instead returns nothing if i send the json cordinates that i'm currently sending but if i send a simple JSON it returns just fine.

AJAX

```
var JSONObj = {"test" : "test1"};
var PointsOnCanvas = [{"PX":486,"PY":447,"CX":485,"CY":447},{"PX":485,"PY":447,"CX":487,"CY":443},{"PX":487,"PY":443,"CX":490,"CY":438},{"PX":490,"PY":438,"CX":499,"CY":423},{"PX":499,"PY":423,"CX":500,"CY":421},{"PX":500,"PY":421,"CX":512,"CY":402},{"PX":512,"PY":402,"CX":519,"CY":392},{"PX":519,"PY":392,"CX":532,"CY":371}]
$.ajax({
            url: "/Ajax",
            type: "GET",
            //datatype: "json", //could be xml, json, html, text or script
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSONObj,//JSON.stringify(PointsOnCanvas),
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response)
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(PointsOnCanvas))
                console.log("response is " + response)
                console.log("json response is " + JSON.stringify(response))
                PointsOnCanvas = [];
            }



        });
```

I have commented out `//JSON.stringify(PointsOnCanvas)` above this is the code that i believe is causing the problem.

The laravel code is below

```
public function RecieveAjax(Request $request){
        if($request->ajax()){
            
            return  response()->json(['result' => $request->all()]);
        }else{
            return "Not Helo";
        }
    }
```

Comment: does `$request->json()` return anything?

Comment: yes if i send JSONObj the simple obj it returns just fine but when i send the PointsOnCanvas it never works

Comment: That's because your `PointsOnCanvas` is an array of values, instead of an object with values. Try something like `data: { points: PointsOnCanvas }`.

Comment: {"Points" : JSON.stringify(PointsOnCanvas)} and {"Points" : PointsOnCanvas} both return nothing